OpenEdx Tutor Palm Version Studio Unable to Load Custom index.js Content
I am unable to fully load the index.js content in the Studio panel. A screenshot is attached.
Studio theme static folder not able to compile js file. Due to this issue custom js activity is not happening in studio Palm version. 
tried to run
tutor images build openedx


The Theme Studio static folder isn’t mapping with the static files, so we need to apply our changes to the following file path:

edx-platform/cms/static/js/index.js

Then, run the collectstatic command again and verify everything works correctly.

openedx-assets build

This is a temporary solution because I encountered the same issue, and it was resolved using this process.
